# Fifteen Puzzle Empty Tile

Tags: javascript, html, null, tiles

I'm currently doing the Fifteen Puzzle and trying to write a function that will return the html id of the html tile element that is holding the empty tile. So far I'm only getting null results. Does someone know a solution to this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Fifteen Puzzle Part III </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="FifteenPuzzlePart3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">

{
border : 0;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}

body
{
font-family : "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size : 16pt;
}

#page
{
background-color: black;
color   : white;
height   : 20em;
margin-left  : auto;
margin-right : auto;
text-align  : center;
width   : 15em;
}

#puzzleTitle
{
font-size:25pt;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

#puzzleBoard
{
height  : 75%;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right: auto;
width  : 75%;
}

#button
{
background-color: grey;
height   : 2.2em;
margin-left  : auto;
margin-right : auto;
width   : 8em;
}

.square
{
float   : left;
margin   : 1px;
padding-left : 1px;
padding-bottom : 1px;
width   : 2.5em;
}

.tile
{
background-color: red;
border   : solid white;
font-size  : 25pt;
}


.tile15
{
background-color: transparent;
border   : none;
}

.clear
{
clear: left;
clear: right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="puzzleTitle">The Fifteen Puzzle</div>
<div id="puzzleBoard">
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile0">1</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile1">2</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile2">3</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile3">4</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile4">5</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile5">6</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile6">7</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile7">8</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile8">9</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile9">10</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile10">11</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile11">12</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile12">13</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile13">14</div>
</div>
<div class="square">
<div class="tile" id="tile14">15</div>
</div>
<div class="square tile15">
<div id="emptyTile"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="button">Click For New Puzzle</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";


window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("button").onclick=scrambleTiles;
}

function getTileElement(tileNumber)
{
 var prefix;
 var result;

 prefix="tile";
 result="";

 if(document.getElementById(prefix+tileNumber)!==null)
 {
  result=document.getElementById(prefix+tileNumber);
 }

 else
 {
  result=null;
 }
 return result;

}

function swapInfo(element1, element2)
{
 var tmp;
 var tmp2;
tmp=element1.className;
element1.className=element2.className;
element2.className=tmp;

tmp2=element1.innerHTML;
element1.innerHTML=element2.innerHTML;
element2.innerHTML=tmp2;

}

function getEmptyTile()
{
 var i;
 var prefix;
 var result;

 i=0;
 prefix="tile";
 result="";

 while(i<15 && result !== null)
 {
  if(getTileElement(i).className==="square tile15")
  {
   result=result+prefix+i;
  }
   i=i+1;
 }

 return result;
}

function scrambleTiles()
{
 swapInfo(document.getElementById("emptyTile"),document.getElementById("tile"+getRandomInteger(14)));
}

function getRandomInteger(upperLimit)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random()*(upperLimit+1));
};
```

Comment: Did my Answer help? or am i missing something?

Comment: Hello, do you need somemore help?

Comment: There was actually a lot more messed up with my program, so it was hard to tell. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

> if(getTileElement(i).className==="square tile15")

the class `"square tile15"` is of the parent node, not the current.

```
<div class="square tile15">
    <div id="emptyTile"></div>
</div>
```

or in the swap function since you are passing the *innerNodes*

```
swapInfo(document.getElementById("emptyTile"),document.getElementById("tile"+getRandomInteger(14)));
```

but it is all a bit confusing.

On finishing your code i would recomend posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get input on optimizing/improving the code.

I hope this helps.